# DBpedia SPARQL - getting image and resource link of other artists?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

Given a musical artist, I am trying to find other musical artists who have the most common "associatedActs of" with a particular artist. I have the following query for Eminem and it works fine

```
SELECT ?c (COUNT(*) AS ?count) WHERE {
{
?b <http://dbpedia.org/property/associatedActs> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Eminem>.
?b <http://dbpedia.org/property/associatedActs> ?
}
}group by ?c order by desc(?count) LIMIT 10
```

But I would like to get back the picture of the artist as well as their dbpedia resource link (?c) adding. Trying this

```
SELECT ?c (COUNT(*) AS ?count) WHERE {
{
?b <http://dbpedia.org/property/associatedActs> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Eminem>.
?b <http://dbpedia.org/property/associatedActs> ?c.
?c <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/thumbnail> ?i
}
}group by ?c order by desc(?count) LIMIT 10
```

gives me an error "Variable ?i is used in the result set outside aggregate and not mentioned in GROUP BY clause". If i groupby by i it works fine but I can't get ?c back.

So how can I get the picture and the resource link other matching artists?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use sub-queries:

```
SELECT ?c ?i ?count WHERE { {SELECT ?c (COUNT(*) AS ?count) WHERE {
{
?b <http://dbpedia.org/property/associatedActs> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Eminem>.
?b <http://dbpedia.org/property/associatedActs> ?c .

}
} group by ?c order by desc(?count) LIMIT 10} . ?c <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/thumbnail> ?i }
```

you can find the result [here](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20?c%20?i%20?count%20WHERE%20%7B%20%7BSELECT%20?c%20%28COUNT%28%2a%29%20AS%20?count%29%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A?b%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/property/associatedActs%3E%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/Eminem%3E.%0D%0A?b%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/property/associatedActs%3E%20?c%20.%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%7D%20group%20by%20?c%20order%20by%20desc%28?count%29%20LIMIT%2010%7D%20.%20?c%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/ontology/thumbnail%3E%20?i%20%7D&format=text/html&timeout=0&debug=on).

Answer (score 1):

Just like in SQL, you can use GROUP BY with multiple variables.

This seems to work:

```
SELECT ?c (COUNT(*) AS ?count) ?i WHERE {

?b <http://dbpedia.org/property/associatedActs> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Eminem>.
?b <http://dbpedia.org/property/associatedActs> ?c.
?c <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/thumbnail> ?i

} GROUP BY ?c ?i ORDER BY desc(?count) LIMIT 10
```

See the results [here](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20?c%20%28COUNT%28%2a%29%20AS%20?count%29%20?i%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A?b%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/property/associatedActs%3E%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/Eminem%3E.%0D%0A?b%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/property/associatedActs%3E%20?c.%0D%0A?c%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/ontology/thumbnail%3E%20?i%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%20GROUP%20BY%20?c%20?i%20ORDER%20BY%20desc%28?count%29%20LIMIT%2010&format=text/html&timeout=0&debug=on).